# Real Time Messaging Issue in React Native using gifted Chat and socket

Tags: javascript, react-native, sockets, websocket

When the chat window is in focus, a connection is established. However, when I navigate away from the chat window, the connection is disconnected. As a result, I am not receiving messages in real time. This issue is occurring in both on-the-spot messaging within the chat window. I have to go IN and OUT to receive the message. Appreciate your help

react native version 0.71.8

Conversations (index.tsx)

```
import {
  GetAllMessages,
  GetAllMessagesForChannel,
  GetChannelDetails,
} from "../../../api/user.get";

import Socket from "../../../components/Socket";
// ....

const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

const Conversations = ({ navigation, route }: any) => {
// .....

  const getChannelMembers = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await GetChannelDetails(item?.id);
      if (resp?.status === 200) {
        setmembers(resp?.data?.data?.members);
        setchannelDetails(resp?.data?.data);
        // updateMessagesWithUserInfo();
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      handleApiError(error?.response);
    }
  };

  const getMessages = async () => {
    try {
      if (type === "channel") {
        const resp = await GetAllMessagesForChannel(item?.id);
        const formattedMessages = resp?.data.map((msg: any) => ({
          _id: msg._id,
          text: msg.message,
          createdAt: new Date(msg.created_at),
          isHashed:
            msg?.hashed === "true" || msg.hashed === true ? true : false,
          image:
            msg?.media && msg?.media?.length === 1 ? msg?.media[0]?.url : null,
          media: msg?.media && msg?.media ? msg?.media : null,
          note: msg?.note,
          deleted_at: msg?.deleted_at,
          user: {
            _id: msg.from,
            name: msg?.username,
            avatar: msg?.from === user?.id ? user?.picture?.url : null,
          },
        }));
        setMessages(formattedMessages?.reverse());
      }
      if (type === "user") {
        const resp = await GetAllMessages(item?.id, user?.id);
        const formattedMessages = resp?.data.map((msg: any) => ({
          _id: msg._id,
          text: msg.message,
          createdAt: new Date(msg.created_at),
          isHashed:
            msg?.hashed === "true" || msg.hashed === true ? true : false,
          image:
            msg?.media && msg?.media?.length === 1 ? msg?.media[0]?.url : null,
          media: msg?.media && msg?.media ? msg?.media : null,
          note: msg?.note,
          deleted_at: msg?.deleted_at,
          user: {
            _id: msg.from,
            name: msg?.fromUser?.name,
            avatar:
              msg?.from === user?.id
                ? user?.picture?.url
                : item?.picture?.url ?? Images?.avatarURI,
          },
        }));
        setMessages(formattedMessages?.reverse());
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      handleApiError(error?.response);
    } finally {
      setisLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const initPusher = () => {
    Socket.init();
    Socket.setConnectionStateListener((status: any) => {
      console.log(">>> connection-status", status);
    });

    try {
      Socket.on(`chat.${item?.id}`, getMessages);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error subscribing to channel:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setisLoading(true);
    getMessages();
    if (type === "channel") {
      getChannelMembers();
    }
    initPusher();
    return () => {
      Socket.close();
    };
  }, []); //call when there is new message

  useEffect(() => {
    if (unreadMessages > 0 && type === "user") {
      handleMarkAsRead();
    }
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  const onStartRecord = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
      audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
        setRecordSecs(e.currentPosition);
        setRecordTime(
          audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition))
        );
      });
      // console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error starting recording:", error);
    }
  };

  const onStopRecord = async () => {
    console.log("onStopRecord");
    try {
      const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
      audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
      const audioBase64 = await getBase64FromFilePath(result);
      // console.log(
      //   "audioBase64",
      //   "data:audio/mp4; codecs=opus;base64," + audioBase64
      // );
      setrecording("data:audio/mp4; codecs=opus;base64," + audioBase64);
      setRecordSecs(0);
      // console.log("REs", result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error stopping recording:", error);
    }
  };

  const getBase64FromFilePath = async (filePath: string) => {
    try {
      const fileContent = await RNFS.readFile(filePath, "base64");
      return fileContent;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error reading file:", error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const onStartPlay = async () => {
    console.log("onStartPlay");
    try {
      const msg = await audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer();
      // console.log(msg);
      audioRecorderPlayer.addPlayBackListener((e) => {
        setCurrentPositionSec(e.currentPosition);
        setCurrentDurationSec(e.duration);
        setPlayTime(audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)));
        setDuration(audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.duration)));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error starting playback:", error);
    }
  };

  const onPausePlay = async () => {
    await audioRecorderPlayer.pausePlayer();
  };

  const onStopPlay = async () => {
    console.log("onStopPlay");
    audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
    audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
  };

  const onOpenPicker = async () => {
    await ImageCropPicker.openPicker({
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      // cropping: true,
      mediaType: "any",
    })
      .then((file: any) => {
        console.log('File', file)
        settempSelectedImg(
          Platform?.OS === "android" ? file?.path : "file://" + file?.path
        );
        setviewImagemodal(!viewImagemodal);
        setvisible(!visible);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        setvisible(!visible);
      });
  };

  const onOpenCamera = async () => {
    await ImageCropPicker.openCamera({
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
      mediaType: "photo",
    })
      .then((image: any) => {
        settempSelectedImg(
          Platform?.OS === "android" ? image?.path : "file://" + image?.path
        );
        setviewImagemodal(!viewImagemodal);
        setvisible(!visible);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        setvisible(!visible);
      });
  };

  const onDocumentClick = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
        copyTo: "documentDirectory",
        mode: "import",
        allowMultiSelection: false,
      });
      const fileUri: any = result[0].fileCopyUri;
      setFilePath(fileUri);
      setIsAttachFile(true);
      setvisible(!visible);
      setFileVisible(!fileVisible);
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("User cancelled file picker");
        setvisible(!visible);
      } else {
        console.log("DocumentPicker err => ", err);
        setvisible(!visible);
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };

  const renderInputToolbar = (props: any) => {
    return (
      <MessageInput
        text={inputText}
        onAttachmentClick={() => setvisible(!visible)}
        onHashTagClick={() => setisHashOn(!isHashOn)}
        onChangeText={(text: any) => setinputText(text)}
        onSend={() => handleSend()}
        isHashOn={isHashOn}
        onStartRecord={onStartRecord}
        onStopRecord={onStopRecord}
        onStartPlay={onStartPlay}
        onPausePlay={onPausePlay}
        onStopPlay={onStopPlay}
        currentDurationSec={currentDurationSec}
        currentPositionSec={currentPositionSec}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderSenderMessage = (props: any) => {
    const { currentMessage } = props;
    return <Sender message={currentMessage} />;
  };

  const renderReceiverMessage = (props: any) => {
    const { currentMessage } = props;
    return <Receiver message={currentMessage} />;
  };

  const renderMessage = (props: any) => {
    const { currentMessage } = props;

    const { user } = props;
    if (currentMessage?.user?._id === user?._id) {
      return renderSenderMessage(props);
    }
    return renderReceiverMessage(props);
  };

  const handleSend = async () => {
    if (!inputText && !tempSelectedImg && !recording && !filePath) return;
    setisSending(true);
    setviewImagemodal(false);
    setFileVisible(false);
    const newMessage: any = {
      _id: messages.length + 1,
      text: inputText
        ? isHashOn
          ? base64?.encode(`<p>${inputText.trim()}</p>`)
          : `<p>${inputText.trim()}</p>`
        : null,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: {
        _id: user?.id,
        name: user?.name,
        avatar:
          user?.picture?.url ??
          "https://skoogstjerna.se/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/640px-Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png",
      },

      sent: true,
      received: true,
      isHashed: isHashOn,
      media: [{ url: `${!tempSelectedImg ? filePath : tempSelectedImg}` }],
      note: recording,
    };
    const post = new FormData();
    post.append("from", Number(user?.id));
    post.append("to", Number(item?.id));
    post.append("hashed", isHashOn);
    post.append("trusted", true);
    post.append("seen", false);
    if (inputText !== "") {
      post.append(
        "message",
        isHashOn
          ? base64?.encode(`<p>${inputText.trim()}</p>`)
          : `<p>${inputText.trim()}</p>`
      );
    }
    if (tempSelectedImg) {
      const fileType = tempSelectedImg.endsWith(".mp4") ? "video/mp4" : "image/jpg";
      post.append("media[]", {
        uri: tempSelectedImg,
        type: fileType,
        name: `${tempSelectedImg?.split("/")?.pop()}`,
      });
    }
    if (filePath) {
      post.append("media[]", {
        uri: filePath,
        type: "application/pdf",
        name: `${filePath?.split("/")?.pop()}`,
      });
    }
    if (recording !== "") {
      post.append("note", recording);
    }

    // const post = {
    //   from: user?.id,
    //   to: item?.id,
    //   hashed: isHashOn,
    //   trusted: true,
    //   seen: false,
    //   message: isHashOn ? base64?.encode(inputText.trim()) : inputText.trim(),
    //   note: recording ? recording : null,
    // };
    try {
      if (type === "channel") {
        const resp = await SendMessageToChannel(item?.id, post);
        if (resp?.status === 200) {
          setMessages((previousMessages: any) =>
            GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, newMessage)
          );
          setisSending(false);
          setinputText("");
          settempSelectedImg("");
          setrecording("");
          setFilePath("");
          setIsAttachFile(false);
        }
      } else {
        const resp = await SendMessage(item?.id, user?.id, post);
        if (resp?.status === 200) {
          setMessages((previousMessages: any) =>
            GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, newMessage)
          );
          setisSending(false);
          setinputText("");
          settempSelectedImg("");
          setrecording("");
          setFilePath("");
          setIsAttachFile(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error, 'catch')
      handleApiError(error?.response);
    } finally {
      setisSending(false);
    }
  };

  const handleMarkAsRead = async () => {
    try {
      type === "channel"
        ? await MarkAsReadChannel(item?.id)
        : await MarkAsRead(item?.id);
      // const resp = await MarkAsRead(item?.id);
    } catch (error: any) {
      handleApiError(error?.response);
    }
  };

  const updatedChatMessages = messages.map((message: any) => {
    const userData = members.find(
      (user: any) => user.id === message?.user?._id
    );
    if (userData) {
      return {
        ...message,
        userName: userData?.name,
        userPicture: userData?.picture?.url,
      };
    } else {
      return message;
    }
  });

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingComponent />
  ) : (
    <Screen>
      <TopHeader
        title={item?.name}
        id={item?.id}
        item={item}
        showTitle
        phone={type === "channel" ? false : true}
        showMore={type === "channel" ? false : true}
        showInfo={type === "channel" ? true : false}
        showBack
        navigation={navigation}
        onInfoPress={() =>
          navigation?.navigate(Screens?.ChannelMembers, {
            members,
            channelDetails,
          })
        }
      />
      <GiftedChat
        messages={updatedChatMessages}
        // isTyping={true}
        renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
        renderMessage={renderMessage}
        renderChatEmpty={() => (
          <TextCustom
            tx={isLoading ? "common.loadingMessages" : "common.noMessages"}
            style={styles?.EmptyText}
          />
        )}
        messagesContainerStyle={
          messages?.length == 0 && { transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }] }
        }
        user={{
          _id: user?.id,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          height: isKeyboardVisible && Platform?.OS === "ios" ? RH(2) : RH(5),
        }}
      />
      <ImagePickerComponent
        visible={visible}
        setvisible={setvisible}
        onOpenPicker={onOpenPicker}
        onOpenCamera={onOpenCamera}
        onDocumentClick={onDocumentClick}
      />
      <ViewImageBeforeSending
        modalVisible={viewImagemodal}
        setModalVisible={setviewImagemodal}
        uri={tempSelectedImg}
        onSend={() => {
          handleSend();
          console.log("handleSend()");
        }}
        inputValue={inputText}
        onChangeInput={(text: any) => setinputText(text)}
      />
      <InChatFileTransfer
        fileVisible={fileVisible}
        setFileVisible={setFileVisible}
        uri={filePath}
        onSend={() => {
          handleSend();
          console.log("handleSend()");
        }}
        inputValue={inputText}
        onChangeInput={(text: any) => setinputText(text)}
      />
      <Loader loading={isSending} />
    </Screen>
  );
};

export default Conversations;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "100%",
  },
  EmptyText: {
    fontSize: fontSize?.Tiny,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: colors?.editColor,
    marginTop: RH(65),
  },
  pdfContainer: {
    // Style your PDF container as needed
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderRadius: 8,
    // Add other styles for size, alignment, etc.
  },
  pdfThumbnail: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },

  pdfImage: {
    width: 50, // Adjust the width and height according to your design
    height: 50,
    resizeMode: "cover", // Or another appropriate resizeMode
    borderRadius: 5, // Apply border radius if needed
  },
});
```

Socket (Index.tsx)

```
import Pusher, { Channel } from "pusher-js";

const APP_KEY = "enfo_key";
const CLUSTER = "mt1";
// const ChannelId = 'channel.5'
const MsgSent = ".chat.message_sent";
// const MsgEdit = "channel.message_edit";
// const MsgDelete = "channel.message_delete";
const SocketEndPoint = "echo.gob";

class Socket {
  pusher: Pusher;
  subChannels: Channel[] = [];

  State = {
    initialized: "initialized",
    connecting: "connecting",
    connected: "connected",
    unavailable: "unavailable",
    failed: "failed",
    disconnected: "disconnected",
  };

  // 1
  init() {
    this.pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, {
      cluster: CLUSTER,
      encrypted: true,
      broadcaster: "pusher",
      wsHost: SocketEndPoint,
      wsPort: 900,
      forceTLS: false,
    });
  }

  // 2 (Optional)
  setConnectionStateListener(listener: Function) {
    if (!this.pusher) {
      throw "pusher is NULL, please call init() first";
    }

    this.pusher.connection.bind("state_change", function (states) {
      // states = {previous: 'oldState', current: 'newState'}
      // $("div#status").text("Channels current state is " + states.current);
      listener(states.current);
    });
  }

  connect() {
    if (!this.pusher) {
      throw "pusher is NULL, please call init() first";
    }
    this.pusher.connect();
  }

  // 3
  // onNewMessage(channelId: string, callback: Function) {
  //   if (!this.pusher) {
  //     throw "pusher is NULL, please call init() first";
  //   }
  //   const ch = this.pusher.subscribe(channelId);
  //   ch.bind(MsgSent, (d: any) => {
  //     console.log("data", d);
  //     callback(d);
  //   });

  //   this.subChannels.push(ch);
  // }

  // 3
  /**
   * Subscribe to different events in a channel
   *
   * @param channelId Channel
   * @param onNewMessage callback to receive a new message in chat
   */
  on(channelId: string, onNewMessage: Function) {
    if (!this.pusher) {
      throw "pusher is NULL, please call init() first";
    }
    const ch = this.pusher.subscribe(channelId);
    ch.bind(MsgSent, onNewMessage, (data: any) => {
      console.log("@@DATAAAA", data);
    });
    this.subChannels.push(ch);
  }

  // 4 (last)
  close() {
    if (!this.pusher) {
      throw "pusher is NULL, please call init() first";
    }
    try {
      // this.pusher.unsubscribe(MsgSent);
      this.pusher.connection.unbind("state_change");
      this.pusher.unbind_global();

      this.subChannels.map((ch) => ch.unsubscribe());
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}

export default new Socket();
```

I want real time messages with in the chat window.